# HSCROLL and VSCROLL in Combobox

Tags: c++, winapi, combobox, scrollbar, win32gui

I have successfully created a combobox with `HSROLL` as follows :

```
HWND find = CreateWindowEx(0, WC_COMBOBOX, _T(""), CBS_DROPDOWN | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD |     
                           CBS_AUTOHSCROLL | WS_HSCROLL | WS_VSCROLL,0, 1, 100 30,
                           hwndToolbar, (HMENU)0, ghinst, NULL);

SendMessage(find, CB_SETHORIZONTALEXTENT, (WPARAM)1000, 0);
```

But it also gives the `VSCROLL`, even if there are only 2 items. This is very ugly. If I drop the `WS_VSCROLL`, it solves the problem.

On the other hand, I also used :

```
SendMessage(find, CB_SETMINVISIBLE, (WPARAM)20, 0);
```

to show 20 items only, other items are showed by `VSCROLL`. The VScroll bar will appear only if there are more than 20 items. So I can not drop `WS_VSCROLL`.

Do you have any idea about how to use 'CB_SETHORIZONTALEXTENT' without VSCROLL bar when there are fewer items ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the height of the combo box is too small to accommodate the number of items. As many items will be shown on drop down, as the height specified. If items cannot fit into this height, then the vertical scroll bar will appear.